# Selecting top % of rows in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a sample dataframe as below (actual dataset is roughly 300k entries long):

```
        user_id   revenue  
 ----- --------- --------- 
    0       234       100  
    1      2873       200  
    2       827       489  
    3        12       237  
    4      8942     28934  
  ...       ...       ...  
   96       498    892384  
   97      2345        92  
   98       239      2803  
   99      4985     98332  
  100       947      4588
```

which displays the revenue generated by users. I would like to select the rows where the top 20% of the revenue is generated (hence giving the top 20% revenue generating users).

The methods that come closest to mind for me is calculating the total number of users, working out 20% of this ,sorting the dataframe with `sort_values()` and then using `head()` or `nlargest()`, but I'd like to know if there is a simpler and elegant way.

Can anybody propose a way for this?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Suppose You have dataframe `df`:

```
user_id revenue
234     21  
2873    20  
827     23  
12      23  
8942    28  
498     22  
2345    20  
239     24  
4985    21  
947     25
```

I've flatten revenue distribution to show the idea.
Now calculating step by step:

```
df = pd.read_clipboard()
df = df.sort_values(by = 'revenue', ascending = False)
df['revenue_cum'] = df['revenue'].cumsum()
df['%revenue_cum'] = df['revenue_cum']/df['revenue'].sum()
df
```

result:

```
   user_id  revenue  revenue_cum  %revenue_cum
4     8942       28           28      0.123348
9      947       25           53      0.233480
7      239       24           77      0.339207
2      827       23          100      0.440529
3       12       23          123      0.541850
5      498       22          145      0.638767
0      234       21          166      0.731278
8     4985       21          187      0.823789
1     2873       20          207      0.911894
6     2345       20          227      1.000000
```

Only 2 top users generate 23.3% of total revenue.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the case for `df.quantile`, from pandas [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.quantile.html) if you are looking for the top 20% all you need to do is pass the correct quantile value you desire.

A case example from your dataset:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'user_id':[234,2873,827,12,8942],
                           'revenue':[100,200,489,237,28934]})
df.quantile([0.8,1],interpolation='nearest')
```

This would print the top 2 rows in value:

```
     user_id  revenue
0.8     2873      489
1.0     8942    28934
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually find useful to use `sort_values` to see the cumulative effect of every row and then keep rows up to some threshold:

```
# Sort values from highest to lowest:
df = df.sort_values(by='revenue', ascending=False)

# Add a column with aggregated effect of the row:
df['cumulative_percentage'] = 100*df.revenue.cumsum()/df.revenue.sum()

# Define the threshold I need to analyze and keep those rows:
min_threshold = 30
top_percent = df.loc[df['cumulative_percentage'] <= min_threshold]
```

The original df will be nicely sorted with a clear indication of the top contributing rows and the created 'top_percent' df will contain the rows that need to be analyzed in particular.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are looking for the cumulative top 20% revenue generating users. Here is a function that will help you get the expected output and even more. Just specify your dataframe, column name of the revenue and the n_percent you are looking for:

```
import pandas as pd

def n_percent_revenue_generating_users(df, col, n_percent):
    df.sort_values(by=[col], ascending=False, inplace=True)
    df[f'{col}_cs'] = df[col].cumsum()
    df[f'{col}_csp'] = 100*df[f'{col}_cs']/df[col].sum()
    df_ = df[df[f'{col}_csp'] > n_percent]
    index_nearest = (df_[f'{col}_csp']-n_percent).abs().idxmin()
    threshold_revenue = df_.loc[index_nearest, col]
    output = df[df[col] >= threshold_revenue].drop(columns=[f'{col}_cs', f'{col}_csp'])
    
    return output
    
n_percent_revenue_generating_users(df, 'revenue', 20)
```